# Normal Distribution Question: Finding mean and standard deviation given probabilities.

Tags: normal-distribution

I would love it if someone could help me with this question:

"The masses of textbooks in a school bag of a student have a normal distribution (normal dist.) with mean $\mu$ and standard distribution $\sigma$. $10\%$ of the books have masses exceeding $900$g and $5\%$ have masses less than $750$g. Find the value of $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

I've gotten so far as to obtain that:

$$\begin{aligned}
P(X > 900) &= 0.1&\\
\implies P(Z < \frac{900 -\mu}{\sigma}) &= 0.9&\\
\implies \frac{900-\mu}{\sigma} &\approx 1.29 &(\text{by normal dist. table})
\end{aligned}$$
However, I don't really know how to get my second equation which would be something along the lines of:
$$\frac{750-\mu}{\sigma} \approx \ ???$$
As $0.05$ is too low of a number to be featured on the normal dist. table, which leads me to believe that what would be the z-value here to be negative ($\frac{750-\mu}{\sigma} \text{ is }< 0$) which doesn't really help me as I don't know $\frac{750 - \mu}{\sigma}$'s positive 'counterpart'.

Any hints or clear answers would be appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT: angryavian has provided me with the motivation to finish the question!

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry of the standard normal distribution, $P(Z < z) = 0.95$ implies $P(Z < -z) = 0.05$. Similar to how you were able to obtain the z-score for $0.9$, I presume you can also get the z-score for $0.95$. If you negate this z-score, you'll get the negative value that $\frac{750-\mu}{\sigma}$ should be equal to.

Comment: Thanks! This provided the motivation for me to finish the question, didn't think of assigning a variable to $\frac{750-\mu}{\sigma}$!